# Цвета в HTML

Tags: html, css

Привет! Можете подсказать, как пишутся цвета, когда пишете сайт в блокноте. И как они обозначаются.

Comment: Точно так же, как и когда пишете сайт в Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2):

```
#1177CC;
#black;
rgb(128,13,200);
rgba(128,13,200,0.5);
hsl(120,60%,70%);
hsla(120,60%,70%,0.8);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p style="color: #000;">По <span style="color: #FFF;">разному</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот хороший ресурс http://stm.dp.ua/web-design/color-html.php

Цвет, а рядом код.

Answer (score 0):

[Цвета смотреть тут](http://colorschemedesigner.com) - удобная штука. Одновременно позволяет сделать гарантированно непротивный диз. 
Хотя что-то действительно хорошее наобум вряд ли получится.